# Geo Json Query - List all records by checking if given geo point lies within the radius of the record's geo point

Tags: database, mongodb, geojson, geo

I am building an application where a user searches for a service provider based on location.

The following needs to be considered

- I save the lat, long for all the service providers and the radius of their servicing area say 5kms
- Users can search for service providers from any location and I grab the lat, long of the users current location from my frontend.

Lets consider I have the following details

Service providers:
S1 : {lat: xxxx, long: xxxx, radius: 5km}
S2 : {lat: xxxx, long: xxxx, radius: 6km}

and so on..

Now when a user searches from a particular lat, long I need to list all the service providers in a way where the user's lat, long falls inside the service providers radius.

That would be I need to list all the service providers where distance between user's geo point and Provider's geo point is less than the providers radius

How can I achieve this using mongodb geoSpatial queries ?

Comment: You may also want to consider using MongoDB Atlas Search, which supports combining full text search and Geo searches in a natural and performant way.   https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/near/#geojson-point-example

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the MongoDB Geo queries, you will need to store the coordinates in either legacy coordinate pairs,

```
{loc:[long, lat], radius: 5}
```

or as [GeoJson objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/index.html#geojson-objects)

```
{loc:{type:"point",[long, lat]}, radius: 5}
```

You will also need a [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#dsphere-indexes) on the `loc` field

When you search, first use [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/index.html#geonear-aggregation), specifying a field name for `distanceField` and the radius of the Earth in `distanceMultiplier` (use the same units as the radius field in the documents).
Then use `$match` to return only documents closer than their corresponding radius.

For example, if the collection contains these documents:

```
{Name:"Prem Fast Food Corner",
 loc:{type:"Point",
      coordinates:[77.2069656,28.6143675]}, 
 radius:15},
{Name:"The Black Beetle",
 loc:{type:"Point", 
      coordinates:[77.0693677,28.5842962]}, 
 radius:10}
```

And there is a 2dsphere index on `loc`, we can query using aggregation to find that Cariappa Parade Ground is within the delivery radius for only one of these restaurants.

```
db.geo.aggregate([
    {$geoNear:{
               near:[77.1385933,28.6653018],
               distanceField:"distance",
               distanceMultiplier:6378,
               spherical:true
    }},
    {$match:{
         $expr:{
             $lte:[ "$distance", "$radius" ]
         }
    }}
])
```